# Retrieving per keyword/field match position in Lucene Solr -- possible?

Tags: lucene, solr

Is there any way to retrieve the match field/position for each keyword for each matching document from solr?

For example, if the document has title "Retrieving per keyword/field match position in Lucene Solr -- possible?" and the query is "solr keyword", I'd like to get, in addition to the doc-id (I normally only want the doc-id, not the full document), something that can tell me the matches are at:

```
solr:
  title: 9
keyword:
  title: 3
```

I'm pretty sure such info is computing during query execution (for phrase queries), but is it possible to return these to the application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Debugging Relevance Issues in Search](http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Debugging-Relevance-Issues-Search) suggest using Solr analysis, which you can get to from the admin URL, using something like `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/analysis.jsp?highlight=on` .
This highlights matching terms and gives their position.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no way to do that directly, but you can use [hit highlighting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters) to implement it.